# Trying to add output link on redirect page to newly created Opportunity from another VF page

Tags: salesforce, apex, visualforce

SF Admin trying to make steps into Dev. Trying to create some web-to-opportunity functionality using combination of Force.com Sites, Apex & VF. It works and the opportunities are created. When the Opp is saved on the VF page, it redirects to another VF page saying Congrats! new Opp created etc. I would like to add an link or button on this redirect page to give the user an option to navigate to the newly created Opp if they want however I'm not having much luck.

Controller:

```
public class OpportunityInformationPage{
    public opportunity oppString{get;set;}

    public OpportunityInformationPage(){
        oppString = new opportunity();
    }
    public PageReference Saveto(){
        opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.name = oppString.name;
        opp.closedate = oppString.closedate;
        opp.stagename = oppString.stagename;
        opp.amount = oppString.amount;
        opp.impact_level__c = oppString.impact_level__c;
        insert opp;

        PageReference reRend = new PageReference('/apex/Opportunity_Created');
        reRend.setRedirect(true);
        return reRend;

    }
}
```

VF Page to input Opp details:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityInformationPage" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="New Opportunity"/>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Saveto}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information">
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.closeDate}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.stageName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.amount}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Impact_Level__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Congrats Page where I would like the link/button to route to SF:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityInformationPage" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:PageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection >
            <apex:outputText value="Congratulations! New Opportunity Succesfully Created" /> <br/>    
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:PageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Any advise, help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Psymn for pointing me in the right direction. The output link was landing me on the Home Tab due to a null Record ID (think this may be because I wasn't using the standard controller - *Dev n00b sorry*). Created a String variable to take the value of the ID and referenced this in the output link which did the trick.

Controller:

```
public class OpportunityInformationPage{
    public opportunity oppString{get;set;}
    public Boolean bOppCreated{get;set;}
    public String opp_sfid{get;set;}

    public OpportunityInformationPage(){
        oppString = new opportunity();
        bOppCreated = false;
        opp_sfid = null;
    }
    public PageReference Saveto(){
        opportunity opp = new opportunity();
        opp.name = oppString.name;
        opp.closedate = oppString.closedate;
        opp.stagename = oppString.stagename;
        opp.amount = oppString.amount;
        opp.impact_level__c = oppString.impact_level__c;
        insert opp;
        bOppCreated = true; 
        opp_sfid = opp.id;
        return null;
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityInformationPage" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <apex:sectionHeader title="New Opportunity"/>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="edit">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Saveto}" rerender="mainBlock"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:outputPanel id="mainBlock">
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information" rendered="{!NOT(bOppCreated)}">
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.name}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.closeDate}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.stageName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.amount}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Impact_Level__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!bOppCreated}">
                <apex:outputText value="Congratulations! New Opportunity Succesfully Created" /> <br/> 
                <apex:outputlink value="/{!opp_sfid}">{!oppString.Name}</apex:outputlink>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:outputpanel>
            </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are redirecting to a new page after creating the opportunity.  Why not just show the success message on your current page and add a link to the new

```
public class OpportunityInformationPage{
public opportunity oppString{get;set;}
public Boolean bOppCreated{get;set;}
public OpportunityInformationPage(){
    oppString = new opportunity();
    bOppCreated = false;
}
public PageReference Saveto(){
    opportunity opp = new opportunity();
    opp.name = oppString.name;
    opp.closedate = oppString.closedate;
    opp.stagename = oppString.stagename;
    opp.amount = oppString.amount;
    opp.impact_level__c = oppString.impact_level__c;
    insert opp;
    bOppCreated = true;
    return null;

}
}

<apex:page controller="OpportunityInformationPage" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<apex:sectionHeader title="New Opportunity"/>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Edit" mode="edit">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!Saveto}" rerender="mainBlock" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:outputpanel id="mainBlock">
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Opportunity Information" rendered="{!NOT(bOppCreated)>
            <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.name}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.closeDate}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.stageName}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.amount}"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!oppString.Impact_Level__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockSection rendered="{!bOppCreated}">
        <apex:outputText value="Congratulations! New Opportunity Succesfully Created" /> <br/>    
        <apex:outputlink value="/{!oppString.id}">{!oppString.Name}</apex:outputlink>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
       </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feeback Psymn...unfortunately the output link is dropping me into the Home Tab and not on the Opportunity. Looks like I need a way to store the ID of the Opportunity created by the page in the controller and pass it back VF to be used in the output link. Would you know how to achieve this?

Comment: Fiddled around with the controller/VF page and finally got it to work. I'll post the revised code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all modify reRend.setRedirect(true) to reRend.setRedirect(false) in your controller
Second thing is that when you want to display messages after cretaion of new opournity ,
Why we need another controller ?..
just after inserting new oppournity in Saveto() method
Add
ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'New oppournity is created'));

Call this message in visual force page by simply mentioning apex:pagemessages/
Now in apex:outputlink mention the newly createtd oppournity </apex:outputlink>